# Calculating logarithm without calculator

Tags: logarithms

I have a short question.
How can I calculate a logarithm without a calculator? 
For example: 
Log base 8 of 4, log base 16 of 2..
Thanks.

Comment: Use $\log_b(b^a)=a$ which translates to  $\log_{c^n}(c^m)=\dfrac{m}{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = \log_{b} x $  is equivalent to $$  x = b^y$$
hence 
$y=\log_{8} 4 $ is equivalent to $$4= 8^y$$ 
$$ 2^2 = 2^{3y}$$ 
since you have same base then you can set the exponents to be equal.
Therefore: $$ 2 =3y$$ 
so $$y=2/3 $$

Comment: If you precede the logarithm name with a backslash: `\log` it will become a LaTeX symbol, rendered in upright font and looking like a function name: $\log$, instead of italic font `log` → $log$, which looks somewhat like a product of three varables $l\cdot o\cdot g$.

Answer (score 2):

for example we have $$\log_8 4=x$$ then we get $$8^x=4$$ and this is equivalent to
$$2^{3x}=2^2$$ thus we get
$$3x=2$$ or $$x=\frac{2}{3}$$
or write
$$\log_{16} 2=x$$ then we get $$16^x=2$$ thus we get $$2^{4x}=2^1$$ and we get
$$x=\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

More general way to do it is as follows

1. Convert it to the natural logarithm for $N > 1$
   $$\log_{10}(N) = \frac{\ln(N)}{\ln(10)}$$
2. Use the following property$$\ln(N)=-\ln\left(\frac1{N}\right)=-\ln\left(1 - \left(1-\frac1{N}\right)\right)$$
3. Use Taylor series for $\ln(N)$ up to a required precision
   $${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\ln(1-x)&=-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{n}}{n}}=-x-{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}-{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-\cdots &&{\text{ for }}|x|<1\\\ln(1+x)&=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n+1}{\frac {x^{n}}{n}}=x-{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-\cdots &&{\text{ for }}|x|<1\end{aligned}}}$$